# why is bookmarks.getTree() not working in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, bookmarks

I was trying to port a chrome extension to Firefox but bookmarks.getTree() kept returning weird results.  I've made a minimal extension to test this.

The code should print the tree to console.  I have 0 bookmarks so it should print a very small array.  Instead it is printing an array of some 400,000 characters, and bookmarks that no longer exist.

Here's my complete test.js code:

> ```
> function firefoxtree(result){
>   var len = JSON.stringify(result).length;
>   console.log("firefox bookmarks  size:" + len);
>   console.log(result);
> }
> browser.bookmarks.getTree(firefoxtree);
> ```

Here's my manifest:

> ```
> {
>   "manifest_version": 2,
>   "name": "My test Extension",
>   "version": "0.01",
>       "browser_action":{
>       "default_popup": "popup.html"
>   },
>   "permissions": [ "bookmarks"],
>
>   "background": {
>     "scripts": ["test.js"],
>     "persistent": false
>   }
>
> }
> ```

And here's the html (just for completeness):

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> </html>
> ```

The result is a tree of old bookmarks that don't exist.  Here's a screenshot:
[image: too many results]

And a screenshot of my bookmarks.
[image]

I have tried clearing the cache, restarting my browser, restarting my computer, and looking for known firefox bugs.  No change.

Anyone have any clue what is going?

update: It appears to be loading some sort of backup.  Creating a bookmark has the same issue.  It reports as success, but nothing appears in my bookmarks.  Bookmark creation is also working with this same mysterious backup.
Anyone know of perhaps a flag of some sort that tells firefox to work on backups?